# Problem with xna shader

Tags: c#, xna, shader, blur, glow

Trying to make a glow effect in xna but it doesn't show the glow or any change at all. Also my back color is purple instead of black and I can't change that either :

```
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(bulletRenderTarget);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        foreach (Bullet bullet in bulletList)
        {
            Texture2D bulletTexture = textures[bullet.bulletType];

            spriteBatch.Draw(
                bulletTexture,
                new Rectangle(
                    (int)bullet.position.X,
                    (int)bullet.position.Y,
                    bulletTexture.Width,
                    bulletTexture.Height
                ),
                null,
                Color.White,
                MathHelper.ToRadians(bullet.angle),
                new Vector2(
                    bulletTexture.Width / 2,
                    bulletTexture.Height / 2
                ),
                SpriteEffects.None,
                0
            );
        }
        spriteBatch.End();

        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
        postProcessEffect.CurrentTechnique = postProcessEffect.Techniques["Blur"];

        spriteBatch.Begin();
            spriteBatch.Draw(
            bulletRenderTarget,
            new Vector2(0, 0),
            Color.White
        );
        GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Additive;
        foreach (EffectPass pass in postProcessEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {
            pass.Apply();
            spriteBatch.Draw(
                bulletRenderTarget,
                new Vector2(0,0),
                Color.White
            );
        }

        DrawHud();
        foreach (BaseEntity entity in entityList)
        {
            entity.Draw(gameTime);
        }
        spriteBatch.End();
```

I'm only trying to get the bullets to glow.

shader :

```
 float BlurDistance = 0.002f;
 sampler ColorMapSampler : register(s1);

 float4 PixelShaderFunction(float2 Tex: TEXCOORD0) : COLOR
 {
  float4 Color;

  // Get the texel from ColorMapSampler using a modified texture coordinate. This
  // gets the texels at the neighbour texels and adds it to Color.
  Color  = tex2D( ColorMapSampler, float2(Tex.x+BlurDistance, Tex.y+BlurDistance));
  Color += tex2D( ColorMapSampler, float2(Tex.x-BlurDistance, Tex.y-BlurDistance));
  Color += tex2D( ColorMapSampler, float2(Tex.x+BlurDistance, Tex.y-BlurDistance));
  Color += tex2D( ColorMapSampler, float2(Tex.x-BlurDistance, Tex.y+BlurDistance));
  // We need to devide the color with the amount of times we added
  // a color to it, in this case 4, to get the avg. color
  Color = Color / 4; 

  // returned the blurred color
  return Color;
 }

 technique Blur
 {
  pass Pass1
  {
   PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PixelShaderFunction();
  }
 }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: None, it just doesn't work it shows the normal gameplay except for the black backscreen, that becomes purple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's purple is because you have

```
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(bulletRenderTarget);
```

which should be the other way around, so changing that into

```
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(bulletRenderTarget);
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
```

fixes the purple problem, to fix the shader change the following in the fx file

```
sampler ColorMapSampler : register(s0);
```

And change your `spriteBatch.Begin()` into

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, null);
```

Some extra info:

the `s0` points to the first texture on the graphics device, which is the one that supplied by `spriteBatch.Draw`, if you want to use `s1` you'd have to set it on the `GraphicsDevice` first by using:

```
GraphicsDevice.Textures[1] = bulletRenderTarget;
```

the `SpriteSortMode.Immediate` just forces the `spriteBatch.Draw` to draw the sprite immediately, if you don't set it it'll create a batch and draw them all at once, but this will be to late because it needs to be drawn when the `EffectPass` is being applied.

As for the blur you could lower the value of `BlurDistance`, but you'd have to try, you can also look up how to do a bloom shader, usually gives a nice effect too.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it all, could you elaborate on the register and the spritesortmode, what does that do exactly ?

Also how can I reduce my blurriness, I only blured it because I wanted the bullets to glow, but now my bullets are glowing and blurred

Comment: @Quincy Added it to the answer

Comment: Thanks, I hope the bloom looks a bit better :)